# How to Implement MVP in Console Application?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp, console-application

I have following code in Program.cs in console application

```
class Program : IView
{
  private static ViewPresenter _presenter;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      _presenter = new ViewPresenter(this);  
  }
}
```

but I cant pass `this` to presenter, as Main method is `static`. Now how could I make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `Program`. Main is a static method.

```
class Program : IView {
    private static ViewPresenter _presenter;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        _presenter = new ViewPresenter(new Program());  
    }
}
```